# Install perl Template-Toolkit for bugzilla on windows

Tags: windows-7, perl, xampp, bugzilla, cpan

Im attempting to install Bugzilla on my local development server (based on a windows machine). My server is the standard xampp install. Ive got to the point where i need to install the relevant perl modules but one of them (Template-Toolkit) does not seem to be recognised. I originally attempted to install it via ppm, but on running bugzillas checksetup file, at the very end i get the following message:

```
COMMANDS TO INSTALL REQUIRED MODULES (You *must* run all these commands
and then re-run this script):

    ppm install Template-Toolkit
*** Installation aborted. Read the messages above. ***
```

but ive already run `ppm install Template-Toolkit` and it worked with no apparent errors. After seeing another post on here, i tried the the CPAN bugzilla bundle:

```
cpan Bundle::Bugzilla
```

but again, no luck. Is there anything else i can try to get this installed?

im using windows 7 pro 64bit and perl 5.10.1 (that came with the xampp install)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xampp installs Perl 5.10.1, but Bugzilla only works with 5.8.1

Comment: Any version starting with 5.8.1

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Template: ppm install Template.

P.S. Strawberry Perl is easier to use on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

I have Activeperl version 5.20.1 installed separately from xampp. And I am getting the following error when accessing bugzilla:

Software error:

```
Template creation failed: failed to create context: failed to load Bugzilla/Template/Context.pm: Can't locate Bugzilla/Template/Context.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Bugzilla::Template::Context module) (@INC contains: . lib C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib) at C:/Perl64/site/lib/Template/Config.pm line 82.
For help, please send mail to the webmaster (postmaster@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

How do I resolve this error so that I can install the template-Toolkit package for bugzilla?

Comment: This does not appear to answer the author's question.